# How to render html file in Ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have multiple HTML files with videos, images and animations. How to render such files in IONIC project? In order not to manually generate separate pages for each html file.  (In my project i use Ionic 3.19.0)
Maybe someone has already encountered such a problem and how you solved this?